# Algorithm for finding conditional minimal difference in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, min

Suppose you have an array of distinct integers : A=[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5...]
I need to find two elements of the array, say A[i] and A[j] such that i is less than j and A[j]-A[i] is minimal .

Is the following a valid solution?

1. First sort the array and keep track of the original index of each element (ie : the     index of the element in the ORIGINAL (unsorted) array.
2. Go through the sorted array and calculate the differences between any two successive   elements that verify the initial condition that the Original Index of the bigger element is   bigger than the original index of the smaller element.
3. The answer would be the minimum value of all these differences.

Here is how this would work on an example:

```
A=[0,-5,10,1]  (in this case the result should be 1 coming from the difference between      A[3] and A[0])
sort A : newA=[-5,0,1,10]
since OriginalIndex(-5)>OriginalIndex(0), do not compute the difference
since OriginalIndex(1)>OriginalIndex(0),we compute the difference =1
since OriginalIndex(10)>OriginalIndex(1), we compute the difference =9
The result is the minimal difference, which is 1
```

Comment: Your first sentence is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks eliot I fixed it now . Any clues if that approach might work ?

Comment: if you sort the input you get :[-1,0,2,10] then take the first two elements : -1 and 0. In the previous, unsortred array  -1 is AFTER 0 so the initial condition  "i is less than j and A[j]-A[i] is minimal" is not verified because i is bigger than j . Then you move on to 0 and 2 , the difference is 2. This is difference us valid since the element 2 is AFTER element 1 in the unsorted array. Then you move on to 2 and 10, the difference is 8. The smallest difference found was 2 so this is the answer . What do you think ?

Comment: The difference has to be positive, sorry about that. Would the algorithm work if I was only looking for the minimum positive difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, it is O(n^2) in time but O(1) in space.  In pseudocode:

```
for i = 0; i < array.length; i++
    for j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++
        if a[j] - a[i] < min
            min = a[j] - a[i]
return min
```

Comment: This takes O(n^2) , I am looking for O(nlog(n)) , any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to find is the positive minimum difference, then basically, your problem is:

```
Find two closest elements in an array.
```

The O(nlogn) solution is straightforward:

1. sort -- O(nlogn)
2. get the difference between two neighboring elements and find the smallest one -- O(n)

So the overall running time is O(nlogn)

You don't have to care about the index.  Because what you what is `abs(A[i]-A[j])=abs(A[j]-A[i])`, it doesn't matter `i>j` or `j>i`

Comment: What you said is correct. However, for the purpose of this problem, I am only looking for the smallest difference A[j]-A[i] between two elements that verify the Initial condition j>i (in the initial array). Does my algorithm look okay ?

Comment: @user2205925 No.  Because you skip some potential answers because of ``i>j`` or ``j>i`` which actually does not matter. For example, ``[1,0,3,5]``

Comment: I mean does it work if I am NOT looking for the absolute minimum difference , but the minimum difference that verifies the condition i<j ?

Comment: If what you're looking for is NOT absolute value, then O(n) algorithm is straightforward: B[k] (1<=k<=n) keeps the index of the largest element in the range A[1...k]. B[k+1] = k+1 if A[k+1] > A[B[k]], otherwise B[k+1] = B[k].